# custom tableviewcell different positions for different devices

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout, constraints, frontend

I'm currently trying to center a UILabel in a custom tableviewcell so that the label will be centered regardless of the device that downloads the app. I know the answer is somewhere in constraints, but I've added them in multiple ways and the UILabel's position continues to change relative to the different device sizes. I'll include a picture of my storyboard at the moment for reference. I know this problem must have a simple answer, but the many answers I've found so far amount to, "add constraints" which doesn't seem to be working.

The current prototype cell with constraints added

[image]

The uncentered text

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1OO0.png):

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUfny.png): [image]

Comment: From what you have shown, everything looks correct. It's hard to guess what the problem might be. I have done exactly what you have described several times and it worked. You could try to look at the layout with the view debugger.

Comment: How are the constraints from your UITableview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. I was using a standard Viewcontroller as the delegate and datasource for the tableview. I tried switching to a tableviewcontroller and the constraints are now being accepted